# Splitting stake accounts

Tags: web3.js, stake

I want to unstake some amount. I have activation and active accounts. Before I want to unstake activating accounts.

Can I split stake account in activating state or only in active state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accounts with state activating can be splitted